# C# Update List by adding new items, updating existing items and deleting uncommon items in least iteration

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, linq, list

I need to update my existing list with data of new list. As shown below:

I have a list A with is binded to my UI element. I need to update the items data of List A with items of List B without assigning List A with list B. As shown below:

```
List A:
{
{id: 1, value: AAA},
{id: 2, value: DDD},
{id: 3, value: CCC},
{id: 4, value: BBB}
}

List B:
{
{id: 1, value: ZZZ},
{id: 5, value: XXX},
{id: 3, value: YYY},
{id: 4, value: BBB}
}

Finally after updation we should have value in List A as below:

List A:
{
{id: 1, value: ZZZ},
{id: 5, value: XXX},
{id: 3, value: YYY},
{id: 4, value: BBB}
}
```

What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
A.RemoveAll(aItem => B.All(bItem => aItem.id != bItem.id));
A.ForEach((aItem) => { aItem.value = B.First(bItem => aItem.id == bItem.id).value; });
A.AddRange(B.Where(bItem => A.All(aItem => aItem.id != bItem.id)));
```

Row #1 deletes uncommon items. Row #2 updates common items between thetwo lists. And row #3 adds B-unique items.

Comment: Yes This seems to be great. But can we reduce iteration. As this will make lot of iteration over the list.

Comment: What you're trying to achieve results in ListB. If you delete all missing items in B from A, then update all common items with values in B and then add all B-unique items, you're literally creating B again.
So unless you didn't want to know each step separately, of course you can use @ronaldm's answer which is the fastest way :)×Comments may only be edited for 5 minutes×Comments may only be edited for 5 minutes×Comments may only be edited for 5 minutes

Answer (score 1):

You can do a `Clear()` and then `AddRange()` for the second list.

```
ListA.Clear();

ListA.AddRange(ListB);
```